# Application threads stopped error due to GC promotion failed

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Application threads are getting stopped due to GC promotion failed.

I have gone through some article which has suggested to add CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction and UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly parameters.

But these are already added, any help will be appreciated.

I am using following parameters:

```
-Xmx4g
-XX:NewSize=3g
-XX:MaxNewSize=3g
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Errors:

```
1297124.414: [GC (Allocation Failure) 1297124.414: [ParNew (promotion failed): 2612841K->2548943K(2752512K), 1.5045391 secs]1297125.919: : [CMS: 983433K->404021K(1048576K), 1.8793447 secs] 3350334K->404021K(3801088K), [Metaspace: 96430K->96430K(1140736K)], 3.3842095 secs] [Times: user=4.51 sys=0.11, real=3.39 secs]
1297127.798: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 3.3858771 seconds
1298669.399: [GC (Allocation Failure) 1298669.399: [ParNew (promotion failed): 2624713K->2557604K(2752512K), 4.8006870 secs]1298674.200: : [CMS: 986964K->404609K(1048576K), 1.8381660 secs] 3450625K->404609K(3801088K), [Metaspace: 96443K->96443K(1140736K)] 3450625K->404609K(3801088K), [Metaspace: 96443K->96443K(1140736K)], 6.6391571 secs] [Times: user=9.36 sys=1.83, real=6.64 secs]
1298676.039: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 6.6427251 seconds
```

Comment: Crossing my fingers for you, but I think: your question is too broad; or more specifically: I doubt that you will get good answers here. You see, **your** application stack leads to this problem within the JVM; and chances to identify the root cause and a reasonable fix via "remote" debugging ... imho: close to zero. I guess: you will need some **real** JVM / GC profiling expert sitting in front of your **machine**, and do profiling; and studying of GC output logs to understand what is going on; and how to really fix that.

Comment: There is no *error* here. But potentially some bad tuning resulting in suboptimal performance. It seems like you have 3G young gen, 1G old gen and the old gen was running full without a concurrent cycle happening before that. Maybe more context (complete GC logs) would help